# How to upload a file larger than 2MB to SharePoint document library using Managed Client Object Model for Silverlight

Tags: client-object-model, file-upload, silverlight

I can't seem to upload a file to SharePoint if that file exceeds 2MB or so. I am developing a Silverlight application that is interacting with SharePoint via Managed Client Object Model for Silverlight (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight).

I've read around that the proper file uploading from Client Object Model should be done like so:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, 
    targetUrl, fileStream, true);
```

However, I cannot use the `SaveBinaryDirect(...)` method because it doesn't exist in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight` assembly.

Right now, I am using this (that's the code that doesn't cope well with +2MB files):

```
FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
...
File file = this.list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

Uploading of files is done inside the following method:

```
public File UploadFile(string fileName, System.IO.Stream fileStream, bool overwrite)
{
    FileCreationInformation fci;
    StringBuilder sb;
    File file;

    fci = new FileCreationInformation();
    fci.Content = this.ReadFully(fileStream);
    fci.Overwrite = overwrite;
    fci.Url = fileName;

    file = this.list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
    return file;
}
```

The catch is in the `ReadFully(System.IO.Stream fileStream)` method and setting the byte array size to a fixed value:

```
private byte[] ReadFully(System.IO.Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms;
    int read;

    buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The idea was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723478/sharepoint-2010-upload-file-using-silverlight-4-0). It may appear a bit clumsy (there's no guarantee that the file size will not exceed `16 * 1024` bytes), but it works. With a little tweaking, this problem can be overcome as well.

Comment: why not set the buffer to the size of the file if that is going to be a problem?